# Process Substitution and Exit Codes

Tags: bash

I would like to monitor the output of a process for a given period of time. The following does everything I want except give me the return value of the command that ran.

```
cmd='cat <<EOF
My
Three
Lines
EOF
exit 2
'

perl -pe "if (/Hello/) { print \$_; exit 1 }" <(echo "$cmd" | timeout 
5 bash)
```

Does anyone have a way to get that return value? I've looked at other questions here, but none of the answers apply in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Bash 4.4-Only Answer: Use $! to collect PID, and `wait` on that PID

Bash only made it possible to collect the exit status of a process substitution in version 4.4. Since we need to have that version anyhow, might as well use automatic FD allocation too. :)

```
exec {psfd}< <(echo "hello"; exit 3); procsub_pid=$!
cat <&$psfd           # read from the process substitution so it can exit
exec {psfd}<&-        # close the FD
wait "$procsub_pid"   # wait for the process to collect its exit status
echo "$?"
```

...properly returns:

```
3
```

---

In the context of your code, that might look like:

```
cmd() { printf '%s\n' My Three Lines; exit 2; }
export -f cmd

exec {psfd}< <(timeout 5 bash -c cmd); ps_pid=$!
perl -pe "if (/Hello/) { print \$_; exit 1 }" <&$psfd
echo "Perl exited with status $?"
wait "$ps_pid"; echo "Process substitution exited with status $?"
```

...emitting as output:

```
Perl exited with status 0
Process substitution exited with status 2
```

---

#### Easy Answer: Do Something Else

While it's possible to work around this in very recent shell releases, in general, process substitutions eat exit status. More to the point, there's just no need for them in the example given.

If you set the `pipefail` shell option, exit status from any component in a pipeline -- not just the last -- will be reflected in the pipeline's exit status; thus, you don't need to use a process substitution to have `perl`'s exit status be honored as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o pipefail

cmd() { printf '%s\n' My Three Lines; exit 2; }
export -f cmd

timeout 5 bash -c 'cmd' | perl -pe "if (/Hello/) { print \$_; exit 1 }"
printf '%s\n' \
  "Perl exited with status ${PIPESTATUS[1]}" \
  "Process substitution exited with status ${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
```